# Python Match Case: checking for types inside of iterable of unknown length

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable, typechecking, iterable-unpacking

I want to check an iterable of unknown length (let's say a list ) contains only a given type (let's say float) using match case (there are other cases, only this one gives me problems).

case [*elems] if all([isinstance(elem, float) for elem in elems]):
return num

This one seems to work, but is really un-pythony. It seems there should be a simpler way.
Can you help me?

I tried [float()], list[float()], list[float], and [float(), *elems]. None of them do the trick.

Comment: There is no simpler way currently builtin the match syntax. It's imo slightly more pythonic (and faster) to not use a list comprehension and instead pass a generator comprehension into `all`. You can also create a helper function `all_isinstance`.